# Retrieve original argument name in function

Tags: swift

I have a function that takes a dictionary key (parsed from a JSON file) and returns the value if it can be cast as a string, or an empty string if it can't be cast or doesn't exist.  The function itself works fine, but I want to have it log a warning if the value is invalid/missing and I'm not sure what the best way to do it is.  I know I could just pass the text of the key as a second argument, but the function is going to be running many times so I was hoping for something more elegant.  Is it possible to retrieve the original argument/key from within the function, or might there be some better way of doing this?

```
let someDict = [String:Any]()

func getStringObject (fromKey: Any?) -> String {
    if let object = fromKey as? String {
        return object
    } else {
        print("Invalid or missing value for ???, using default.") // want to print the original argument or at least the key string
        return ""
    }
}

let someString = getStringObject(someDict["someInvalidKey"]) // should print someDict["someInvalidKey"] or someInvalidKey
```